# Loading specific text failed

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I work swift 3.2 to work multi-lang app

for each of the lproj files and LocalisedString, I create key-value pair as :

"User Email"; = "登入電郵";

It is possible to print the path of Bundle but I simply cannot use the localised string instead.

```
Containers/Bundle/Application/0C630DFA-2AB8-48AA-9BE2-3FD6524716C1/TaxIRD.app/zh-Hant.lproj
```

Would you please tell. me which way we can change the app language by user preference ?

Here is my working

```
extension String {

    func localized(lang:String , key:String) ->String {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        print(path ?? "nil path")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        //Bundle.main.lo
        return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
    }...
```

ViewController

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(lcode, forKey: "lang")
if lcode == "tw" {
    lcode = "zh-Hant"
}else if lcode == "cn" {
    lcode = "zh-Hans"
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to try [Localize-Swift](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift) for this.

Comment: I have tried pod install but the framework cannot be loaded. https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semicolon ; after `"User Email"`. Sure that is not the problem? Change it to `"User Email" = "登入電郵";`